# SQLAlchemy - get date that table was created

Tags: python, oracle, oracle11g, sqlalchemy, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm connecting to an Oracle database from sqlalchemy and I want to know when the tables in the database were created. I can access this information through the sql developer application so I know that it is stored somewhere, but I don't know if its possible to get this information from sqlalchemy.

Also if its not possible, how should I be getting it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with sqlalchemy, but in sql you can query USER_OBJECTS (or ALL_OBJECTS) - `select created from user_objects where object_name = 'MY_TABLE' and object_type = 'TABLE'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SqlAlchemy doesn't provide anything to help you get that information. You have to query the database yourself.

something like:

```
with engine.begin() as c:
    result = c.execute("""
        SELECT created
          FROM dba_objects
         WHERE object_name = <<your table name>>
           AND object_type = 'TABLE'
    """)
```